# Angular environment for many stagings

Tags: angular, npm

I build version for deploy and need to have onfigurations for prod, staging1 and staging2.
I have files in environments folder:

```
environments.ts
environments.prod.ts
environments.staging1.ts
environments.staging2.ts
```

In Angular.json I have sections:

```
"configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
            "staging1": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging1.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging2": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging2.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
```

When I call command for example like that:

```
call npm install
call npm run prod --configuration staging1
```

it takes still first environment file: `environment.prod.ts` file, not `environment-staging1.ts`

---

In package.json I have build commands like that:

```
{
  "name": "finant",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node start.js && ng serve",
    "build": "node pre-build.js && ng build --configuration=prod --output-hashing=none --extra-webpack-config webpack.extra.js",
    "prod": "npm run build && node build.js",
```

And this is problem, because when I change to --configuration=staging1 it works, but I have to change it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to work, you need to passe the configration using double `--`

```sh
npm run prod -- --configuration staging1
```

Comment: I added comment to my post

Comment: Above command doesn't work because it still call build from package.json with `--configuration=prod`